# Error while Receiving JSON List

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm using JSON to do two things at the same time First I want to send (Username & Password) to PHP File that Reads the toggle buttons status from database for Username and Password and PHP File also sends the toggle status using JSON List to Application 
I Combined both Reading and Also Sending the Username and Password but it always states in the Logcat an error

JSON Code i'm using Combined Sending User and Password and Receiving JSON List According to that username and Password

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(fishtank.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            /*Temp
                SharedPreferences settings =  getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 us = settings.getString("storedWifiUser", "");
                    ps = settings.getString("storedWifiPass", "");
                 try {
                     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
                     json.put("user", us); 
                     json.put("pass", ps);

                     postData(json);


                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();}  Temp */
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();   
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }

           /* public void postData(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try { 
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                    List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);    
                    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));
                    //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");  
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                    if(response != null) {
                        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        //input stream is response that can be shown back on android
                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } */
            //Temp
             @Override

             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 try {
                    // Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                    // Log.i("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

                    // System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

                     //Temp
                     JSONObject json2= new JSONObject();
                     SharedPreferences settings =  getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                     us = settings.getString("storedWifiUser", "");
                        ps = settings.getString("storedWifiPass", "");
                     try {

                         json.put("user", us); 
                         json.put("pass", ps);

                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();}
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        try { 
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                            List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);    
                            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json2.toString()));
                            //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");  
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                            Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                            if(response != null) {
                                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                                //input stream is response that can be shown back on android
                            }

                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                     //Temp
                     JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("status");
                     String tog1="";
                     String tog2="";
                     String tog3="";
                     if(c.has("fil"))

                            tog1 = c.getString("fil");

                        if(c.has("HEA"))
                         tog2 = c.getString("HEA");

                        if(c.has("LED"))
                            tog3 = c.getString("LED");

                        Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                                        if(tog1.equals("ON"))
                                        {   toggle1.setChecked(true);}
                                        else{ toggle1.setChecked(false);}
                                             if(tog2.equals("ON"))
                                             {   toggle2.setChecked(true);}
                                             else{   toggle2.setChecked(false);}
                                             if(tog3.equals("ON"))
                                             {    toggle3.setChecked(true);}
                                             else{toggle3.setChecked(false);}

                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }

             }






        }//End Json
```

PHP File

```
    <?php ("Content-type:text/css")

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","123","pet_home");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// if(isset($_POST['json'])){
        $json=$_POST['json'];
        $data2=json_decode($json,TRUE);
        $u=$data2->{'user'};
        $p=$data2->{'pass'};
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password='$p'");
            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//$row_cnt=1;
             if($row_cnt>0){     
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
                $data = array('success'=>true, 'error'=>'',  'status'=>array("fil" => $row['filter_st'], "HEA"=> $row['heat_st'], "LED" =>$row['led_st'])); 
             }else{
                $data = array('success'=>false, 'error' => 'No records found');
             }               

   //  }else{
    //     $data = array('success'=>false, 'error' => 'No POST value from Android App');
  //   }

     echo json_encode($data);

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Logcat

```
    12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at com.set.petshome.fishtank$JSONParse.onPostExecute(fishtank.java:334)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at com.set.petshome.fishtank$JSONParse.onPostExecute(fishtank.java:1)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-13 10:54:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(8940):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: First of all you should run the network request and maybe parsing in doInBackground to get rid off NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

According to Log some html tag like "
" is coming with your response so set header in php `header("Content-type: text/css")` in php and try again.

Comment: Crashed,Please Check my Updated post with logcat